# PHP ODBC return all records

Tags: php, odbc

I started using PHP with Oracle using ODBC commands.  I used odbc_exec to get to query the database, which seems to work.

I am trying to print the dataset to a text file.  I am able to write to the text file, but for some reason, I am only able to get back 1 record/row from the table.

One query in particular returns over 100 records.  I would like to be able to print all 100 records in the text file.

I have researched all over the web, and I have come close to getting this work.  In fact, I can print all the records to the web page.  I just can't get all of the records into the text file.

Please see my code below and advise what I am missing.

```
 <?php
   $voyage = $_POST['voyage'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM voyageTable WHERE voyage = '".$voyage."'";

   $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

   while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))  // have tried odbc_fetch_row already
   {
     $fullName = odbc_result($result, 1);
   }

   $dateFile = "CMDU-".$voyage."-".date('dmY').".txt";
   $dataString = $fullName . "\n";
   $fWrite = fopen($dateFile, "a");
   $wrote = fwrite($fWrite, $dataString);
   fclose($fWrite);

 ?>
```

I know I am close to getting this.

I have altered the while loop numerous times.  I tried to do this as well:

```
 <?php
   while(odbc_fetch_array($result))
   // ...
 ?>
```

Please help.
That was unsuccessful as well.

Comment: Probable sidenote? `$query = "SELECT * FROM voyageTable WHERE voyage = '".$voyage."';` missing a closing `"` as in `$query = "SELECT * FROM voyageTable WHERE voyage = '".$voyage."'";` - Notice syntax highlighting's off? If it's a typo, edit your question. If it's not, then that'll be an issue.

Comment: You're just overwriting `$fullName` with the most recent result.

Comment: The query I used in this example is not the same query I used on my page.  But all in all, $voyage is the variable I am running the query for.  How do I get the text file to write all of the results?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ where am I overwriting it?  How do I not overwrite it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$fullName = odbc_result($result, 1);
```

You need to either echo out like this:

```
echo  odbc_result($result, 1);
```

Or store the result in an array like this:

```
$fullName[] = odbc_result($result, 1);
```

Just storing the value of each row in $fullname as a variable will overwrite the value and give you the last value from the last row in the result set.

Expanding on ಠ_ಠ's comment.